# HTML input required attribute or ASP.NET MVC Data Annotations required decorator

Tags: asp.net, html

Are there any specific advantages of using one over the other? 
Assuming the browsers will have javascript enabled.

If the error messages have to be customized which one would be more suitable?

Are there any other parameters to evaluate which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old browsers do not support HTML input require attribute.

http://caniuse.com/#search=required

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp